# Could someone help me figure out why I am getting the error malloc(): corrupted top size

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, realloc

## Overview

I am currently trying to create a dynamically expanding array that I'd be able to use in c++ as well as c, the array is contained inside of the structure I call `Train` which has to be initialized with a function called `initialize_train` and has more added to the array with `insert_cart`, when this function is executed it uses the function `realloc` to expands the array by one and then inserts an allocated array via a pointer. The problem I'm incurring occurs when I use the function `malloc` the second time I use `insert_cart`, with the error being **malloc(): corrupted top size**. I've tried figuring out why this occurs for 2 days haven't why it occurs only that it seems to occur the third time I use malloc when the code from line 0 and line 51 remain the same.

## Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const unsigned short CHAR_POINTER_SIZE = sizeof(char*);

typedef struct
{
    char **carts;
    unsigned short count;
} Train;

void initialize_train(Train *train)
{
    train->carts = (char **)malloc(CHAR_POINTER_SIZE);
    train->count = 0;
}

void insert_cart(Train *train, char *text)
{
    char* allocatedText;
    {
        unsigned int length = strlen(text) + 1 ;
        printf("%d: %s\n", length, text);
        allocatedText  = (char*)malloc(length);
        printf("bytes allocated\n");
    }

    train->count += CHAR_POINTER_SIZE;
    train->carts = (char **)realloc(train->carts, train->count);
    
    
    unsigned int index = 0;
    while (*text != '\n')
    {
        allocatedText[index] = *text;
        text++;
        index++;
    }

    train->carts[train->count++] = allocatedText;
}


int main(void)
{
    Train train;
    initialize_train(&train);
    
    
    insert_cart(&train, "cart_0");
    insert_cart(&train, "cart_1");
    insert_cart(&train, "cart_2");
    insert_cart(&train, "cart_3");
    insert_cart(&train, "cart_4");
    insert_cart(&train, "cart_5");
    free(&train);
}
```

## Output

```
7: cart_0
bytes allocated
7: cart_1
malloc(): corrupted top size
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
7: cart_0
bytes allocated
7: cart_1
bytes allocated
7: cart_2
bytes allocated
7: cart_3
bytes allocated
7: cart_4
bytes allocated
7: cart_5
bytes allocated
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems.

Lets start with you loop `while (*text != '\n')` that you use to copy the string (instead of using the standard `strcpy`). This loop will look for the newline to know when to end.

But the strings you pass in to the function don't have any newlines, so your loop will go way out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Either use plain `strcpy` to copy the strings:

```
strcpy(allocatedText, text);
```

Or loop until you get to the string terminator:

```
while (*text != '\0')
```

Another very serious problem is how you use the `count` member of the structure. You using it as both the number of elements, *and* the byte-size for your memory reallocations. It can't be both, only one or the other.

---

After finding more errors, here's a list of them all that I can currently find:

- Your loop to copy the input string doesn't stop on the null-terminator, going out of bounds of the input string.
- Because of the previous problem, you will write out of bounds of `allocatedText`
- You never null-terminate `allocatedText`
- You use `train->count` as the new byte-size for the `realloc` call, and later you use it as an index into the `train->carts` array. It can't be both, only one or the other
- You call `free(&train)` which attempts to free memory not allocated by `malloc`

All of these problems will, one way or another, lead to *undefined behavior* and could explain all your messages and future crashes.

Comment: thank you! Changing it too '\0' fixed the error, but now it has the error `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`

Comment: @joshuawoulfe That's likely the cause of the other problem I mention.

Comment: Maybe, but this is kind of just sticking tape over the problem but subtracting 1 from count does avoid the error.

Comment: @joshuawoulfe When you call `realloc` you use `count` as the *byte size* to reallocate. Later you use `count` as the *element index*. It can't be both, you have to decide on one or the other!

Comment: Also don't think the problem quite rides in just the '\n' because if I modify while loop to print the characters it seems to be going though what ever is stored in the program. the results being "cart_0cart_1cart_2cart_3cart_4cart_5D����xh����x��������`���������j���zRx" and keeps continuing until it hits '\n'

Comment: @joshuawoulfe That *is* the problem: Because the strings doesn't have a newline, you go  on *outside* of the strings, leading to *undefined behavior*. You should stop the loop on the string null-terminator, not the newline.

Comment: @joshuawoulfe And since you go outside of the input strings, you will also go outside of the memory you have allocated for `allocatedText` and write unknown data to unknown memory locations that you're now allowed to write to. This is *also* undefined behavior. And commonly memory allocators store meta-data just before or after allocated memory which means this could lead to corruption of the memory allocator data.

Comment: @joshuawoulfe And on yet *another* note, you never null-terminate the string in `allocatedText` either.

Comment: @joshuawoulfe And to put even more fuel on the fire: With `free(&train);` you try to free data that wasn't allocated by `malloc`.